# Kafka - This server is not the leader for that topic-partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two broker kafka 0.10.2.0 cluster.Replication factor is 2. I am running 1.0.0 kafka stream application against this Kafka. In my kafka stream application, producer config has `retries = 10 and retry.backoff.ms = 100`

After running few minutes, I observed following logs in Kakfa server.log. Due to this Kafka stream application is throwing 'NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION' exception.

What may be the possible reason? Please help me.

```
[2017-12-12 10:26:02,583] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [__consumer_offsets,22] to broker 1:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

Comment: Producer does retry internally on this error and only throws it retires are exhausted -- maybe you have a network issues and thus the producer cannot find the correct broker.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 10):

Each topic is served by one or multiple Brokers - one is leader and the remaining brokers are followers.

A producer needs to send new messages to the leader Broker which internally replicate the data to all followers.

I assume, that your producer client does not connect to the correct Broker, its connect to a follower instead of the leader, and this follower rejects your send request.

Try to run `./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic your_topic --describe`

```
Topic:your_topic    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:retention.ms=14400000
Topic: your_topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
Topic: your_topic   Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: your_topic   Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```

In this example you can see that `your_topic` have 3 partitions meaning all 3 brokers are leaders of that topic each on different partition, s.t `broker 2` is leader on `partition 0` and `broker 0` and `broker 1` are followers on `partition 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But how can I fix the issue `NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION`? What should I correct in the producer?

Comment: if I understand this correctly, with retry > 0 producer should be able to find the correct leader in the subsequent retries.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-219:/opt/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic gameServicPlayerProfile
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 30000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)

Comment: at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:75)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:57)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:54)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)

Comment: I am getting this error what action should I take it

Answer (score 1):

Try setting these properties and see if it helps resolve the issue:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 10);  //increase to 10 from default of 0
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,   
    Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE)); // increase to infinity from default of 300 s
```

([Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/IFtTgEkct4k))

Comment: What does consumer property have to do with this issue?